# Issue with btree algorithm

Tags: java, b-tree

I've been searching all over for some pointers and have been coming up a bit short. I have an assignment for a project where we have to make a btree implementation by extending a 234 Tree class that was given to us.

The `234Tree` class is working while the tree is still a 234 tree. It seems that using the insert method from this class breaks when I try to use this as a btree. I've copied the insert method into my btree class as an override in case I have to change something, that way the 234 tree split will still work.

Here's a link to my btree class at pastebin http://pastebin.com/TcP0UMA2

I use all of this from a command prompt. Here's the output when I run it

```
Enter first letter of show, insert, find, change, read, or quit: s<br/>
level=0 child=0 /20/30/50/70/<br/>
level=1 child=0 /10/<br/>
level=1 child=1 /25/<br/>
level=1 child=2 /35/40/45/<br/>
level=1 child=3 /60/<br/>
level=1 child=4 /80/90/100/<br/>
Enter first letter of show, insert, find, change, read, or quit: i<br/>
Enter value to insert: 85<br/>
Moving 2 items. Those values are 50, 70.<br/> 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException<br/>
    at frankaddeliaproject2.BTree.insert(BTree.java:115)<br/>
    at frankaddeliaproject2.Tree234App.main(Tree234App.java:43)<br/>
```

Java Result: 1

The problem I notice ends up being when the parent node becomes full (in this instance it's order of 5, so it wants to split the node on the 5th insert). That's why when trying to insert 85 it breaks at this point.

```
while(true)
 {

     if( curNode.isFull() )               // if node full,
     {
         split(curNode);                   // split it
         curNode = curNode.getParent();    // back up
                                          // search once
         curNode = getNextChild(curNode, dValue);
      }  // end if(node is full)
```

The `nullPointerException` is at the line that has this statement:

```
if( curNode.isFull())
```

When I look at this block of code I can figure out that it's checking if `curNode` is full, so it'll run through the first time and the issue seems to be coming when

```
curNode = getNextChild //...
```

Because there technically isn't a child after this one. I'm mainly unsure of how to fix it from this point.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!
-Frank

EDIT:
It looks like my link to the class gets a little buried. I'll post it below if that's easier

```
public class BTree extends Tree234 {

public void split(Node thisNode)     // split the node
  {

  // assumes node is full
  int tmp = Node.getOrder();
  int counter = 0;

  //figures out number of children to move during a move (2^n < x < 2^n+1)
  while(tmp >= 2)
  {
    tmp /= 2;
    counter++;
  }

  DataItem[] items = new DataItem[counter + 1];      

  for(int x = counter; x > 0; x--)
  {
    items[x] = thisNode.removeItem();
  }

  DataItem itemB;
  Node parent;
  Node[] children = new Node[counter];
  int itemIndex;

  itemB = thisNode.removeItem();    // this node

  //makes array of children to move
  int tmpcount = 0;
  for(int i = counter; i > 0; i--)
  {
      children[tmpcount] = thisNode.disconnectChild(Node.getOrder() - i);
      tmpcount++;
  }

  Node newRight = new Node();       // make new node

  if(thisNode==root)                // if this is the root,
    {
     root = new Node();                // make new root
     parent = root;                    // root is our parent
     root.connectChild(0, thisNode);   // connect to parent
    }
  else                              // this node not the root
     parent = thisNode.getParent();    // get parent

  // deal with parent
  itemIndex = parent.insertItem(itemB); // item B to parent
  int n = parent.getNumItems();         // total items?

  for(int j=n-1; j>itemIndex; j--)          // move parent's
     {                                      // connections
     Node temp = parent.disconnectChild(j); // one child
     parent.connectChild(j+1, temp);        // to the right
     }
                               // connect newRight to parent
  parent.connectChild(itemIndex+1, newRight);

  // deal with newRight
  // moves items to newRight
  // then alerts how many items are being moved and the values
  String msg = "Moving " + counter + " items. Those values are ";

  for(int y = 0; y < counter + 1; y++)
  {
    if(items[y] == null)
    {
      continue;
    }

    newRight.insertItem(items[y]);

    //build output message
    if(y < counter)
      msg += items[y].dData + ", ";
    else
      msg += items[y].dData + ". ";

  }

  //outputs message
  System.out.println(msg);

  //reconnect children to new parent
  for(int j = 0; j < counter; j++)
  {
      newRight.connectChild(j, children[j]);
  }

  }  // end split()
// -------------------------------------------------------------
// gets appropriate child of node during search for value

public void insert(long dValue)
  {
  Node curNode = root;
  DataItem tempItem = new DataItem(dValue);

  while(true)
     {

     if( curNode.isFull() )               // if node full,
        {
        split(curNode);                   // split it
        curNode = curNode.getParent();    // back up
                                          // search once
        curNode = getNextChild(curNode, dValue);
        }  // end if(node is full)

     else if( curNode.isLeaf() )          // if node is leaf,
        break;                            // go insert
     // node is not full, not a leaf; so go to lower level
     else
        curNode = getNextChild(curNode, dValue);

     }  // end while

      curNode.insertItem(tempItem);       // insert new DataItem
  }  // end insert()
// -------------------------------------------------------------    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you have an underlying problem from just that snippet but you can solve the `NullPointerException` by simply checking `curNode` first.

```
if(curNode != null && curNode.isFull() )               // if node full,
{
    split(curNode);                   // split it
    curNode = curNode.getParent();    // back up
                                      // search once
    curNode = getNextChild(curNode, dValue);
}  // end if(node is full)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! I did that, and then had to fix the subsequent points where it still tries to execute code so that it checks for curNode being equal to null. Unfortunately, I did that to the point where now it won't let it insert the new value. Everything else will go until that point though. Are there any points that you happen to see where curNode is pointing to a null child that I might be able to alter? Thanks!